# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte in django

Tags: python, django, json, utf-8

Сейчас учусь делать проекты на Django и столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть база данных с продуктами, а так же есть dump файл формата json. Этот файл сделал командой `python manage.py dumpdata products.Product > allproduct.json`. Я удалил файл базы данных, чтобы добавить новое поле в админке (странный способ добавления нового функционала, согласен). После выполнил команды миграций `python manage.py makemigrations` `python manage.py migrate`. Проект уже работал как нужно, и теперь мне нужно было вернуть все продукты на место. Это нужно было сделать командой `python manage.py loaddata loaddata products/fixtures/allproduct.json`. На этом моменте я завис, потому что выводится ошибка UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte. Я гуглил, и показывали как исправить эту ошибку на простых примерах типа открытия файла через `with open('file.txt', encoding="utf8") ...`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку в Django проекте? Нужные скрины и код прикреплю по запросу.

Json файл:

```
[
  {
    "model": "products.product",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "╤ьх°эр  шуЁє°ър",
      "image": "products_images/Flim9a8DeAOpNaAOg04N0DgSNSFAaWXOohJcvokXeIModujZfh1Y5-EE7WQxNp_zGpvRX8Ni_w94k0BQ.jpg",
      "price": "500.00"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "products.product",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "name": "┴юы№°р  шуЁє°ър",
      "image": "products_images/┴хч_шьхэш-2.jpg",
      "price": "1000.00"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "products.product",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
      "name": "┴хч ърЁЄшэъш",
      "image": "",
      "price": "23.00"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: в явную сохранить файл в кодировке ютф, следя за отсутствием всяких непечатных символов. файл скорее всего битый.

Comment: Что у вас случилось с кириллицей? Где этот файл открывали что она у вас так отображается и какая кодировка при этом выбиралась? Если это windows, то файл может быть сохранён в windows-1251 (или он же cp1251). Или наоборот, файл в UTF-8, а вы его открываете в редакторе как windows-1251.

Comment: @Alpensin, даже когда поменял неразборчивые символы на латиницу, ничего не поменялось, ошибка осталась
Использую Windows 10 и работаю в PyCharm. Файл json открывал тоже в PyCharm.

Comment: Пересохранить в кодировке utf-8 **без BOM** (это важно)

Comment: @andreymal, перезапись файла действительно помогла, спасибо большое.